# How to analyze strings on Applescript/mac

Tags: macos, applescript, string

How would I write a script to analyze strings in Applescript (or other scripting program for mac)?  Example: scan text file for "I love eating", copy subsequent text, end at ".", so that if my file was "I love eating apples.  I love eating cherries.  I love eating grapes, pecans, and peaches."
it would return "apples  cherries  grapes, pecans, and peaches"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual suspect for processing text in AppleScript is the built-in, global property [`text item delimiters`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_fundamentals.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH218-SW22). You can use it to both break a single string into multiple pieces (when using the `text items … of` reference form), select range endpoints (when using `text item N` in the `text … of` reference form), and join several pieces into a single string (when coercing a list to a string).

```
to pickText(str, startAfter, stopBefore)
    set pickedText to {}
    set minLength to (length of startAfter) + (length of stopBefore)
    repeat while length of str is greater than or equal to minLength
        -- look for the start marker
        set text item delimiters to startAfter
        -- finish if it is not there
        if (count of text items of str) is less than 2 then exit repeat
        -- drop everything through the end of the first start marker
        set str to text from text item 2 to end of str

        -- look for the end marker
        set text item delimiters to stopBefore
        -- finish if it is not there
        if (count of text items of str) is less than 2 then exit repeat
        -- save the text up to the end marker
        set end of pickedText to text item 1 of str

        -- try again with what is left after the first end marker
        set str to text from text item 2 to end of str
    end repeat
    set text item delimiters to " "
    pickedText as string
end pickText

-- process some “hard coded” text
set s to "I love eating apples. I love eating cherries. I love eating grapes, pecans, and peaches."
pickText(s, "I love eating ", ".") --> "apples cherries grapes, pecans, and peaches"


-- process text from a file
set s to read file ((path to desktop folder as string) & "Untitled.txt")
pickText(s, "I love eating ", ".")
```

Comment: Stupid question, though: how would I create text item deliminators that included quote marks?  Obviously """ wouldn't work-

Comment: You can escape the quote character using the backslash: "\""